# Interview Problem (Coloring grid hackerrank Problem for larger inputs)

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

I was giving hackerrank test for some company recently and came across the following question. I searched and found out that it's unsolvable(NP-hard) for the given constraint. Please let me know if you know how to solve this one.

Problem

Calculate the number of ways to color an N * M grid using K colors. Adjacent squares in the grid should have different colors. Squares are considered adjacent if they share an edge.

Constraint : 1<=N,W,K<=10^5
It was asked to print the answer obtained above after taking it's mod with 10^9 +7

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the solution I have found here is the detailed explaination for the question posted in stack exchange by jernej.
Posting the link below.

[problem by Read and Tutte . You are essentially asking for the chromatic polynomial of the grid graph (the vertices of degree 1 do not matter.)See the attached picture from Read R.C. and W.T. Tutte. Chromatic polynomials. In: L.W. Beineke and R.J. Wilson, Selected Topics in Graph Theory, volume 3, pages 15--42.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642921/chromatic-polynomial-of-a-grid-graph)

Comment: I have gone throught that but I don't think it helps in this.